# In Matlab, how can I sort the order of a nested structure?

Tags: matlab, sorting, nested, structure

I am trying to sort the order of a nested structure in descending order by a specified parameter.  Please refer to the following nested structure:

```
struct(1).otherStruct(1).name = 'A';
struct(1).otherStruct(1).classAve = 21;
struct(1).otherStruct(2).name = 'B';
struct(1).otherStruct(2).classAve = 21;
struct(1).otherStruct(3).name = 'C';
struct(1).otherStruct(3).classAve = 21;

struct(2).otherStruct(1).name = 'D';
struct(2).otherStruct(1).classAve = 13;
struct(2).otherStruct(2).name = 'E';
struct(2).otherStruct(2).classAve = 13;
struct(2).otherStruct(3).name = 'F';
struct(2).otherStruct(3).classAve = 13;

struct(3).otherStruct(1).name = 'G';
struct(3).otherStruct(1).classAve = 24;
struct(3).otherStruct(2).name = 'H';
struct(3).otherStruct(2).classAve = 24;
struct(3).otherStruct(3).name = 'I';
struct(3).otherStruct(3).classAve = 24;
```

My goal is to sort the structure above by the highest classAve to the lowest.  I would like to sort by the parent structure "struct".  As an illustration of what I would like the output to be, please refer to the code below.  Notice that the nested structure is now in descending order by classAve but reassigned within the parent structure.

```
struct(1).otherStruct(1).name = 'G';
struct(1).otherStruct(1).classAve = 24;
struct(1).otherStruct(2).name = 'H';
struct(1).otherStruct(2).classAve = 24;
struct(1).otherStruct(3).name = 'I';
struct(1).otherStruct(3).classAve = 24;

struct(2).otherStruct(1).name = 'A';
struct(2).otherStruct(1).classAve = 21;
struct(2).otherStruct(2).name = 'B';
struct(2).otherStruct(2).classAve = 21;
struct(2).otherStruct(3).name = 'C';
struct(2).otherStruct(3).classAve = 21;

struct(3).otherStruct(1).name = 'D';
struct(3).otherStruct(1).classAve = 13;
struct(3).otherStruct(2).name = 'E';
struct(3).otherStruct(2).classAve = 13;
struct(3).otherStruct(3).name = 'F';
struct(3).otherStruct(3).classAve = 13;
```

If anyone has suggestions on an easy way to accomplish this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: does all `otherStruct` in each element of `struct` has the same `calssAve` value?

Comment: I would recommend against such data organization for such a simple data in the first place.

Comment: Shai, yes, all otherStruct in each element of struct always has the same classAve value.

Comment: Oleg, the data I am working with is actually very large/complex.  If I did not use a nested struct, then the organization of data would be too confusing.  Also, I presented the code in the simplest form I could so that my question would not be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd suggest using another variable name (eg `structA`) instead of `struct` since that's a [function to create structs](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

Then to solve your problem (assuming each `otherStruct` child has the same `classAve`):

```
classAve = arrayfun(@(ii) structA(ii).otherStruct(1).classAve,1:numel(structA));
[~, sort_idx] = sort(classAve,'descend');
structAsorted = structA(sort_idx);
```

The first line is the largest hurdle to jump; it extracts the indices of the first `otherStruct` in each array element of the big struct. The following two lines are trivial for sorting stuff.

Comment: In addition, you can also use `classAve = [StructA(:).classAve];`

Comment: @HughNolan no you can't, because there is another intermediate struct.  And something like `structA(:).otherStruct(1).classAve` doesn't work obviously because it cannot be guaranteed that all the `otherstruct`s have the same content, which is required to use scalar indexing on a struct.

Comment: Ah apologies I didn't see there was another layer. You could in theory do `Layer1= [StructA(:).otherStruct]; classAve = [Layer1(:).classAve]` (and get an error if they had different numbers of fields) but that's a bit silly, especially if you have more layers to go down.