# in Matlab, get field values in structs

Tags: matlab, struct, field

Sorry if the question has been asked before, can't find searching.
I have an array of structures (about a 1000). Each struct has a field called "travelTime" which is a 3D matrix of size "120x92x150". I need to look up the value for a certain position for all 1000 matrices, for ex. index (60,46,75) so I would have an array with 1000 elements. I could do it in a for loop, but is there an easier and more elegant way (faster)?

Thanks,
Kamran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy a nice answer from [In Matlab, how can I sort the order of a nested structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205277/in-matlab-how-can-i-sort-the-order-of-a-nested-structure) (thanks @Gunther-Struyf!):

```
Points = arrayfun(@(ii) myStruct(ii).travelTime(60,46,75),1:numel(myStruct));
```

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate everything along a fourth dimension, retrieve all indices and then `squeeze` the result back into a column vector. For example, if your structure array is `S`, you can do this:

```
A = cat(4, S.travelTime);
points = squeeze(A(60, 46, 75, :));
```

#### Benchmarking

Let's benchmark the possible solutions:

```
M = reshape(1:18, 2, 3, 3);
for k = 1:100
    s(k).travelTime = mod(k, 6) * M;
end

tries = 1e4;

%// Vectorized solution
tic
for jj = 1:tries
    A = cat(4, s.travelTime);
    points = squeeze(A(1, 2, 1, :));
end
toc

%// For loop solution
tic
for jj = 1:tries
    points = zeros(size(s));
    for ii = 1:numel(s)
        points(ii) = s(ii).travelTime(1, 2, 1);
    end
end
toc

%// arrayfun solution
tic
for jj = 1:tries
    Points = arrayfun(@(ii)s(ii).travelTime(1, 2, 1), 1:numel(s));
end
toc
```

The results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.072367 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.890323 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.08522 seconds.
```

Not surprisingly, the vectorized solution is the fastest and an `arrayfun` solution is the slowest.

Comment: +1 and I would recommend the OP storing data as a 4 dimensional array in the first place. However, I am not sure this solution is faster (due to precedent MATLAB inefficiencies when dealing with > 2D array) but definitely more memory intensive. It would be nice to see a timing comparison between a simple loop, arrayfun and the cat index method.

Comment: Nice (can you add release and architecture?).

Comment: Except that (assuming `double`), in the OP's case, the 4D solution creates a `120*92*150*1000*8 / 1000^3 = 13`GB *temporary*...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I've never said this is a memory-friendly solution. Then again, the OP _does_ have the original struct already in memory, so I didn't assume that memory was a problem...

Comment: @EitanT: true. And apparently, the OP indeed has 26 GB of RAM to spare :)